# Check a string is contain "+" sign and number only

Tags: android

I have a `String` and sometimes value changed:

```
String str1 = "+25"; // only have "+" sign and number

String str2 = "+Name"; // only have "+" sign and text
```

How can I distinguish these `String` because I want to do something like that:

```
if (isString1Type) { // both strings also have "+" sign
// do something
}
```

Do `String` have any functions for this case.
Can anyone give me suggestions?

Comment: I suppose you need regular expressions (regex) for the pattern.

Comment: As simple and straightforward solution you could just iterate through characters of the string and check each whether it is digit or equal sign or not.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you could do something like this:

```
 String str = "+Name";
 boolean hasPlusSign = str.contains("+");
 boolean isNumber = tryParseInt(str.replace("+", ""));
 if(hasPlusSign && isNumber){ //if the string is +25 for example here will be true, else it will go to the else statement
    //do something
} else {
    //something else
}


boolean tryParseInt(String value) {  
   try {  
       Integer.parseInt(value);  
       return true;  
    } catch (NumberFormatException e) {  
       return false;  
    }  
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the simple regex `"[+][0-9]+"`. It more simple and easy.
Here is example code

```
   String str1 = "+25";
    if (str1.matches("[+][0-9]+")){
        // your string contains plus "+" and number
        // do something
    }eles{

    }
```

Hope this help

Answer (score 0):

You can use regex like this:

[0-9]+ here + means more than one digits from 0-9

```
String str1 = "+25"; 

String str2 = "+Name"; 

String regex = "[0-9]+";

if(isDigit(str1.replace("+",""))){
  Log.d("str1","Integer");
}else{
  Log.d("str1","Not Integer");   
  }

if(isDigit(str2.replace("+",""))){
  Log.d("str2","Integer");
}else{
  Log.d("str2","Not Integer");
 }

boolean isDigit(String str){
  if(str.matches(regex)){
            return true;
        }else {
           return false;
        }
 }
```